# No module named 'Keras' in PyCharm, although it's installed and works fine in the terminal

Tags: python, keras, pycharm, python-import

Following [this tutorial](https://www.pyimagesearch.com/2017/09/29/macos-for-deep-learning-with-python-tensorflow-and-keras/), I have installed keras successfully and when I run python in the terminal and import keras, everything looks fine. However, when I run it using PyCharm, I get this error:

```
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'keras'
```

what should I do?

Comment: Are you using the *exact* same Python version *and* installation? When you start Python interpreter from the terminal (like `python`), try calling `which python` to see the path of the interpreter, and compare it with the one used by PyCharm. See https://www.jetbrains.com/help/pycharm/configuring-python-interpreter.html for how.

Comment: @boramalper when creating the project, I select my project interpreter by choosing the desired virtualenv -which I have keras installed on- manually. So I guess it should work exactly the same way as entering that virtualenv in terminal (using workon) and calling python. Am I right?

Comment: I assume so. Hopefully someone more experienced will help!

Comment: @boramalper Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

mmh I find strange that he doesn't know it but I think you can add it in PyCharm Preferences > Project: your_project > Project Interpreter > '+'.

Or it may be because your Python Interpreter is not the same than which one of terminal but in the same place where you add your module, you can choose the right interpreter.

I'm not sure about that but you can try anyway :)

Comment: Thank you for your help, paying a closer attention to the interpreter in the preference and the one used in the terminal, I noticed they were different as you said. Now that I try to choose the one used in the terminal, it fails due to this error: Please specify a different SDK name

Comment: Oh sorry, I removed other interpreters from the dropdown list and it resolved ,thanks again

Comment: Okay I don't know if I helped you ahah :') But you're welcome